# Impossible to assign a managed identity to my Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, identity

I have been trying to assign a user assigned managed identity or system assigned managed identity, to my Azure function.

However whenever I try and and assign a managed identity, nothing happens. It keeps telling me "Added 1 identity to function" with a green checkmark, both with system assigned and user assigned, but then it reverts back immediately.

I have tried recreating my function (with the same name and a different name) and waiting 1 and 2 days between assigning an identity, with no effect.

I have made a video showing the error https://youtu.be/W9UsYXcsnmg

The weird part about it, is I am able to assign identities to all my other functions, which use the same region, consumption plan and resource group.

I have also made sure it is not a privilege problem, as my Azure administrator has the same issue, but only for this "function".

Has anybody encountered this before or do you have any possible solutions. Right now the function can not connect to our database.

Comment: have you tried deleting and redeploying the function with enabled managed identity using bicep or az cli?

Comment: Interesting. Did not know it was possible to deploy a function with a managed identity directly, still pretty new to the entire Azure platform, but I did try and add a managed identity through the Azure CLI.

Comment: @Thomas That did the trick, good to know, next time Azure refuses to work. Thanks!

Comment: yea Portal is nice to try things quickly but whenever you want reliability & reproducability you definately should go with IaC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thomas, helped me answer my question, so if anyone ever run into the same problem as me, here is what I did.

1. Exported a template from a function that has an identity attached
2. Copied the "identity" part from that template
3. Exported the template from the function that did not work
4. Deleted the function from the Azure platform
5. Inserted the "identity" part from the original template into the new function template
6. Ran a custom deployment with the new template, that is the original function with the new "identity" part